# When retrieving data using Entity Framework Core, I'm getting duplicate data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get the data using Entity Framework Core and using the FromSqlRaw method also using stored procedure in SQL Server: it is different between JSON output and SQL result as follows

```
var ProjectList = db.Projectlist.FromSqlRaw("EXEC [NI].GetProject @ProCode", ProjectProjectCode).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Result is:

```
"totalRowCount": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    }
  ]
```

in the database result

```
ProCode      ProName           Less    Imp       Recom           LastChanged
PR-225/08   RBC CAS Training   YY      HK        ""            2020-06-08 11:31:40.350
PR-225/08   RBC CAS Training   YY      HK        ""            2020-06-08 11:31:40.350
PR-225/08   RBC CAS Training   XXX     XX        ""            2020-06-08 11:31:20.973
PR-225/08   RBC CAS Training   XXX     XX        ""            2020-06-08 11:31:20.973
```

This the query I'm using

```
  SELECT PL.ProID,PS.ProCode,ps.ProName,ll.Less ,ll.Imp,ll.Recom,PL.LastChanged
  FROM ProLessonLearn PL
    INNER JOIN ProStruct AS ps ON ps.ProID = PL.ProId
    INNER JOIN LessLearn AS ll ON ll.LessLeaId = PL.LessLeaId
  WHERE  PS.ProCode = 'PR-225/08' and PL.Active=1   
  ORDER BY PS.ProCode
```

i just find out that without using Entity Framework Core and used the SqlCommand it getting following result

```
{
  "totalRowCount": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "pro Name": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "YY",
      "imp": "HK",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:40.35"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAMMS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "XXX",
      "imp": "XX",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:20.973"
    },
    {
      "proName": "RBC CAMMS Training",
      "proCode": "PR-225/08",
      "less": "XXX",
      "imp": "XX",
      "recom": "",
      "lastChanged": "2020-06-08T11:31:20.973"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can resolve this on the code side. need help with

Comment: *there is different between JSON output and SQL result* - what difference do you see between the JSON and the SQL result? EF doesn't prepare JSON; none of this is EF's fault - you've created a query that has a Cartesian product in it, fix your join conditions so they don't match multiple rows. Ignore anyone who suggests slapping a DISTINCT in there

Comment: You are getting duplicate data because somebody stored the duplicates.

Comment: @jdweng it's not necessarily because the duplicates were stored, but they certainly were selected - `SELECT firstname FROM person` can return duplicate names even if the person table contains no duplicated people. `SELECT orders.* FROM orders JOIN products ON...` can return duplicates because the relationship is 1:many even if neither table contains duplicate data

Comment: @Caius Jard : How would you like buying an item in a stored and then getting charged twice on your credit card?  The OP may of stored the same data twice and may need to remove the duplicates.

Comment: My point is not that you're wrong, I'm just trying to point out that you haven't covered all the cases and indeed, you've covered only a limited and less likely case; duplicate data may or may not be stored, but non-duplciated data can be *turned into* duplicated data by how it is processed and/or selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your join is faulty and generating duplicated data

Take a look at this simpler example of a system that tracks everywhere a person has ever lived:

```
Person - Name, AddressId
John, 1

Address - Id, City, UntilDate
1, Chicago, null
```

This query is OK:

```
SELECT p.* FROM person p JOIN address a ON p.addressid = a.id

John, 1
```

Until we add another address for John moving to New York in 2000:

```
Address - Id, City, UntilDate
1, Chicago, 2000-01-01
1, New York, null

SELECT p.* FROM person p JOIN address a ON p.addressid = a.id

John, 1
John, 1
```

The query wouldn't have duplicates if we showed all the data:

```
SELECT * FROM person p JOIN address a ON p.addressid = a.id

John, 1, 1, Chicago, 2000-01-01
John, 1, 1, New York, null
```

We forgot that the query is part of the business requirement "create a page that shows living users" - in this system a user is marked as having died when they no longer have a current address

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person p JOIN address a ON p.addressid = a.id
WHERE a.untildate is null

John, 1
```

That's better!

So, you're either getting duplicates either because the database really does have duplicates in it (less likely) or because the *subset* of data you're selecting contains repeated data because somewhere in the data you're *not* selecting is the thing that makes it unique. Fix it up, by making sure you exclude the irrelevant data (like I excluded all the user's past addresses)

because the subset of columns you're selecting has repeated data